# Oracle Pivot/Decode

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

Sample Table

```
EmployeeID | AssignmentID | WageCode | CompanyName | BillRate | BillTotal    
     1     |       1      | Regular  | CompanyOne  |   10     |    400
     1     |       2      | Regular  | CompanyTwo  |   11     |    440
     1     |       1      | Overtime | CompanyOne  |   15     |    150
     1     |       1      | Mileage  | CompanyOne  |    0     |     20
     2     |       3      | Regular  | CompanyThree|   20     |    800
     2     |       3      | Regular  | CompanyThree|   20     |    800
     2     |       3      | Overtime | CompanyThree|   30     |     90
     2     |       3      | Mileage  | CompanyThree|    0     |     60
```

I want to only show rows with a WageCode of 'Regular', grouped by EmployeeID, WageCode, AssignmentID, CompanyName and BillRate, and pivot the other wage codes into columns.

The final result should look like this:

```
EmployeeID | AssignmentID  | CompanyName | RegBillRate | RegBill | OTBillRate | OTBill | MileageBill
    1      |      1        | CompanyOne  |    10       |    400  | 15         |    150 |        20
    1      |      2        | CompanyTwo  |    11       |    440  |  0         |      0 |         0
    2      |      3        | CompanyThree|    20       |    1600 |  30        |     90 |        60
```

What's a cleaner way to do this that's not a bunch of with statements like this:

```
with regular as 
(select EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate, sum(BillTotal) Total from SampleTable where wage code = 'Regular' group by EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate
),
overtime as 
(select EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate, sum(BillTotal) Total from SampleTable where wage code = 'Overtime' group by EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate
),   
mileage as 
(select EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate, sum(BillTotal) Total from SampleTable where wage code = 'Mileage' group by EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, BillRate
)
select r.*, o.BillRate, o.Total, m.Total
from regular r 
left outer join overtime o
on r.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID and r.AssignmentID= o.AssignmentID and r.CompanyName= o.CompanyName and r.BillRate= o.BillRateand 
left outer join mileage m
on r.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID and r.AssignmentID= m.AssignmentID and r.CompanyName= m.CompanyName and r.BillRate= m.BillRateand
```

The query above is paraphrased and probably doesn't work.

What's a better way to do this with some combination of decode and pivot?  Is a single pivot table possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PIVOT:** The Oracle PIVOT clause allows you to write a cross-tabulation query starting in Oracle 11g. This means that you can aggregate your results and rotate rows into columns.

**DECODE:** The Oracle/PLSQL DECODE function has the functionality of an IF-THEN-ELSE statement.

For your use case, you can use pivot and decode in the following way:

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName, 
    decode(REG_BILLRATE, NULL, 0, REG_BILLRATE) AS REG_BILLRATE,
    decode(REG_FILL, NULL, 0, REG_FILL) AS REG_FILL,
    decode(OT_BILLRATE, NULL, 0, OT_BILLRATE) AS OT_BILLRATE,
    decode(OT_FILL, NULL, 0, OT_FILL) AS OT_FILL,
    decode(MILEAGE_FILL, NULL, 0, MILEAGE_FILL) AS MILEAGE_FILL 
FROM nbitra.tmp
pivot
(
    max(BillRate) AS BillRate, sum(BillTotal) AS Fill
    for WageCode IN ('Regular' Reg , 'Overtime' OT , 'Mileage' Mileage )
);
```

Note: The code replaces nulls with 0.

Comment: Magical.  This is the most amazing thing I've ever seen.  You are awesome!

Comment: So happy you like the solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Regular' then billrate end) as regular_billrate,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Regular' then BillTotal end) as regular_billtotal,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Overtime' then billrate end) as ot_billrate,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Overtime' then BillTotal end) as ot_billtotal,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Mileage' then billrate end) as mileage_billrate,
       sum(case when WageCode = 'Mileage' then BillTotal end) as mileage_billtotal
from SampleTable st
group by EmployeeID, AssignmentID, CompanyName;
```

Comment: This gets close but you end up with too many rows and then nulls for most of the summed columns.

Comment: @Alex03 . . . Yes, you'll notice that I removed `WageCode` from the `SELECT`, but not from the `GROUP BY`.  Oops.

Comment: My mistake!  I knew what you meant but I still couldn't get it to work for some reason.  But this is a valid solution.  Summing up the bill rate scares me a bit, but in my case it won't matter because the bill rate will be unique inside each group.  Thank you.

Comment: @Alex03 . . . You can use `max()` instead.  I wasn't sure which logic you really wanted.